# WPF: Drawing a single character in a Rectangle

Tags: wpf, text

this time, I have a rather short question: I want to Have a single char (which is a bracket) to display in a given Rectangular area without having spaces between the char an the border of the Rectangle. Is this possible?

//EDIT: What im trying to do is placing brackets around a mathematical term which might be of different height.

greetings

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<Border Background="AntiqueWhite">
    <TextBlock Text="?" />
</Border>
```

I've set the background of the border so you can see it. Normally you'd want to leave it along or have it transparent.

Comment: Thanks, but i think you got me wrong, this will place the Character including its surrounding white areas into the border. I need only the Character, with no white border to be in the Rectangle

Comment: @Robert: In this case you miaght have to draw a bitmap yourself, or convert the character to an outline. Fonts have space aruond the characters for a reason and everything that displays a character from a font will honor that space.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i think you still got me wrong. My Question is primary if i can display a Char without any spacing or border at all (its not about if the space is visible). I can reach that by setting a negative Margin, but that wont work with different Fonts / Fontsizes.